# Convert date string [Quarter to Year] with pandas Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to convert the quarterly data to yearly data using the most recent value of the quarter, But I have a problem with that Raw data as a string[Q] Could not be converted.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2020 Q1','2020 Q2','2020 Q3','2020 Q4'],
                  'value':['5,268','6,166', '7,085', '6,748']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print (df)

df.set_index(['date'],inplace=True)
Y_df = df.resample('Y').last()
Y_df.index = Y_df.index.to_period("Y").astype(str)
print(df)
```

Comment: 2020 Q1 is not a datetime, it's a time range, you can choose a date inside the 2020 Q1 to replace the time range, and do further computations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code with convert string "Q*" to start date of the quarter, which can be used further as per requirement.

```
df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace(r'(\d+) (Q\d)', r'\1-\2')
df['date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.date, freq='Q').to_timestamp()
```

**Output**

```
    date    value
0   2020-01-01  5,268
1   2020-04-01  6,166
2   2020-07-01  7,085
3   2020-10-01  6,748
```